# Crossover Distortion

Tags: audio, distortion

The most common Audio Amplifier uses a NPN and a PNP BJT as an emitter follower to drive a low impedance speaker .This has been true for about 40 years.Some idle current is set up by a biasing circuit to reduce crossover distortion .With no bias and hence no idle current the music will sound terrible at low power.The better circuits used techniques like a  thermally coupled VBE multipler transistor to keep the idle current relatively constant with changes in temp or supply volts.Is there an optimum idle current where distortion in minimised ? Is it only important that the idle current is above a certain amount ? Is it better to run more idle current assuming that power drain and heat are not a problem? The idle current figures given in old magazines for old circuits seem rather nominal .Is there a proper design equation or are there sensible rules of thumb?

Comment: Hi, I didn't think it was true that BJTs are the most common speaker drivers. I would have expected MOSFET drivers to have overtaken BJTs a decade or two ago, though I can't say for sure. (Let's put aside the prospect that, by population of mobile phones, digital TVs, PC chipsets and sound cards, Bluetooth headsets and so on, class D amplifiers through MOSFETs are probably the most common.)

Comment: In Douglas Self's book, Audio Power Amplifier Design there is a section on biasing. I don't have with me at present, but a google search may turn something up.

Comment: The idle current has to be large enough to reduce crossover distortion to an acceptable level over all expected temperatures, supply voltages and variations in device characteristics. I think "rule of thumb" is probably as close as you're ever you're going to get.

Comment: Oh, and yes - the more idle current, the lower the distortion, but obviously the law of diminishing returns applies. 40 years ago nobody cared about wasting a few hundred mW because high quality meant mains powered and battery powered meant low quality.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an optimum idle current where distortion in minimised ?

A lot of folk will always swear by class A power amplifiers because there is no discernible cross over-distortion: -

[image]

So, how much do you want to bias the transistors from being "class B" to "class AB" to "class A" is pretty much down to how little distortion you can tolerate.

Feedback helps a lot because if you have a really fast op-amp driving the final transistor stages, the cross-over distortion is much-reduced by the op-amp actively pushing through this area but, then you get the audiophiles insisting that feedback is bad hence, they go for straight class A with very little feedback and lots of heat generated.

Answer (score 1):

Crossover Distortion is an IMPULSE_SAMPLER of the music content.

For a sinusoid, that impulse_sampler generates only "harmonics", and the standard equipment will show only harmonic-related distortion.

For more interesting music than (pure sin flutes) sins, the combined voltages of multiple non-flute instruments provides unpredictable ZeroCrossings, and those IMPULSE_SAMPLES no longer are harmonically related.

The impulses are broadband; thus all the ear's cochlear tone-responding fibers get stimulated, while the music-expecting auditory cortex gets puzzled by the non-music-correlated energy.

in Douglas Self's book, he has a few pages suggesting the designer adjusts the crossover idling current to match as exactly as possible.

I suggest this approach:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvGEhx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or run class A.

Comment: @ analogsystemsrf              Interesting +1 .So on music it really muddles things where on a sig gen it is not so bad .So crossover distortion is very bad for the ear.

Comment: @ Autistic About 5 years ago, I ground through Doug Self's book. During the repeated readings, I concluded the variable transconductance right around zero-crossings resulted in (1) a fixed gain,which is desired, plus (2) a variable gain, occurring only around the ZC. That variable gain ----- zero everywhere except near the ZC ---- is precisely how an IMPULSE_SAMPLER functions. And that behavior explains why Sinwaves can be reported with such low distortion, yet the music is cruddy.